# jquery autocomplete UI -- positioning image with label

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to include an image in the results of a jquery autocomplete widget.

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
  source: data,
  minLength: 2,
  }).data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li />")
      .data("item.autocomplete", item)
      .append("<a><span><img style=\"max-height: 50px;\" src='" + item.thumbnail + "' />" + item.label + "</span></a>")
      .appendTo(ul);
     }; 
  },
```

My code is working, but I can't seem to figure out how to create space between the image and the text. Right now, my results look as follows:

[image]

As you can see, there's no spacing between the image and the results link (if you look closely, you'll see the start of the "Rue de la Bavole, Honfleur" box to the extreme left).

Is there a simple fix to resolve this issue?

**Solution**

I was able to resolve by putting the text only in the `<a>` tags. Here's the code

```
.append("<img style=\"max-height: 50px; margin-right: 5px;\" src='" + item.thumbnail + "'/>" + "<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding some margin to the style attribute of the image, for example:

change this:

```
.append("<a><span><img style=\"max-height: 50px;\" src='" + item...
```

to this:

```
.append("<a><span><img style=\"max-height: 50px; margin-right: 10px;\" src='" + item...
```

Comment: Thank you -- I've tried something similar...no luck. Adding `<br>` sort of "works" but it puts  the image and label on separate lines (undesirable).

Comment: Oh, the image must be overlapping somehow. Have you tried `display:block` on the image? Can you post your CSS or better yet a working example?

Comment: Overlap is exactly right -- I can work on a getting you a working example, but I can't post the code as is. Unfortunately, `display: block` didn't do the trick.

Comment: Got it -- will post you my solution.